# getting data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

Good morning i'm new Symfony developer and i'm using mongoDb to manage my database, in my case i have a Question document which refer to many Questions here is the code :

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Question", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $questions = array();
```

and when i'm trying de get the data from the database with doctrine manager:

```
$quiz = $dm->getRepository('MYDOC\QuizzBundle\Document\Quizz')->findOneById("quizID");
```

i get a such big error, i'll give its main part :

```
code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException"
```

Any one can help me plz ?

Comment: Please update your question with the full stack trace. As-is, it's not at all clear where the `get_class()` warning is coming from in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an array, but it needs to be an object.
You can use ArrayCollection

```
protected $questions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

Comment: it seems that it is not the problem origin because doctrine manage that in the constructor @Ulti